# Modify Tax label in cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, tax, ce-1.9.2.0

In Cart page I would like to modify the tax label.

Suppose for some rules I've set VAT rate 8% and my English label is **8% VAT**

So in cart page it's appearing like **8% VAT (8%)**

So How can I remove **(8%)** from the last??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anyways I've solved answer by overriding following file in my theme and delete following lines from both code

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\checkout\tax.phtml
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\order\tax.phtml
```

I've removed following code from both files

```
<?php if (!is_null($rate['percent'])): ?>
    (<?php echo (float)$rate['percent']; ?>%)
<?php endif; ?>
```

Done the job.